# Почему при выводе текста на экран нужно писать System.out?

Tags: java, java.lang.system

Почему когда мы хотим вывести текст на языке java мы пишем `System.out`? Что это значит, может кто помочь?

Comment: Ну можете сделать статический импорт и тогда сразу писать `out.println(...)`. Это же банально и просто, вызов статической переменной из класса, вы вообще учили `Java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поверхностно но все же.

**System** - это последний класс из пакета java.lang.

**out** - это переменная класса типа PrintStream, объявленная в классе System.

**println** - метод класса PrintStream.

Comment: Добавить можно то, что вы могли бы сделать `System system=new System();    PrintStream stream=System.out;
            stream.println("text");t` как обычно это вы и делаете. Но, это невозможно сделать по причине того, что класс `System` имеет только `private` конструктор, поэтому, приходится работать со статическими методами класса